# Why Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE starting on two ports by default?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and it starts on two ports by default.

**Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http) 8090 (http)**

**Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) 8090 (http)**

I have tried setting different port using server.port but that overrides only first port 8080 to a different one and 8090 remains. Also tried to change actuator port with management.port to a different one.

I see spring Boot 2.x doesn't have this issue. Any reason why spring boot 1.x runs on two ports by default and how to run on single port?

**application.properties**

```
server.context-path=/test-app

endpoints.actuator.enabled=true

management.security.enabled=false

management.health.defaults.enabled=true

management.health.mail.enabled=false

management.port=8981
```

Comment: Post your application.yml/properties file.

Comment: Presumably the other port is actuator.

Comment: I tried changing management.port to different one also, still that didn't help

Comment: For that to happen, you must have multiple connectors in your application. That requires some code that customizes the embedded Tomcat instance to add another connector.

Comment: don't have any custom code for adding connectors. I am using JAX-RS for APIs, could it be jax-rs adding its own port?

Comment: You have a `spring-boot-actuator` dependency that is exposing another port, it seems. This should work out of the box  (on the same port as your app) so no special configuration is needed.